# Styling a Jquery Mobile Panel

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing my first Jquery Mobile application.  I was able to get my first panel up and running.  I basically want a navigation system of links inside the panel.  I basically use an unordered list (`<ul><li>home</li><li>search</li><li>... etc</li></ul>`) but Whenever I try to style the attributes of the #header_panel below such as the width or height of the `<li>` elemetns, it does not take effect on the page.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated.  I would like to make it so that each `<li>` is underneath each other as well as setting the font size, border, height, width= 100% of panel, etc.  The padding takes effect but the height and width do not.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="header_panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" id="header_panel">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

#header_panel li{
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
padding: 10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is slightly confusing to me, from what I understand you want your LI elements not to take up the entire panel and float to the left.

See if the below helps.

```
#header_panel li{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
```

After the ending UL tag be sure to clear your float.

Comment: yes you are right, this wasn't a jquery mobile issue as was an issue with my HTML markup

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/R3PbF/) with 2 panels. Use the top left and top right buttons to open them.

The one from the top right button uses the data-role="listview" on the UL to get the standard jQM vertical list.  Then CSS is used to further change the styles (font, height, border etc.):

```
<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-theme="c" id="header_panel2">
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>  

/* PANEL 2 STYLES */
#header_panel2 li{
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#header_panel2 a{
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

The one from the top left button uses just CSS to style the list:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-display="overlay" data-theme="c" id="header_panel">
<ul >
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
</div>

/* PANEL 1 STYLES */
#header_panel ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}
#header_panel li{
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#header_panel a{
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

The CSS seems to work fine, are you sure you are not overriding it elsewhere in your project?